# Gate features automatically copied across all annotations

Tags: nlp, gate

I have done a rule based annotation, which annotates different paragraphs. When I add any feature to any paragraph annotation which has been generated, the features are copied across all the generated paragraph annotations (all the annotations are in sync with respect to features). 
The annotation list shows them as different annotations, and there is no exception at any point.
I am unable to understand the reason for this behavior. Anyone here who can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please put example of how you add Features to Paragraph annotations? Also if you see the "feature" as separated Annotation it looks like you add Annotation but not a feature. So,  examples are necessary to understand the issue.

Comment: Thank you, I figured out the problem. While annotating the paragraphs, I was adding a common feature object to all the annotations, instead of creating a new feature for every annotation. Due to this, when I edited the features later, all the features were getting updated. Thanks again for your helo.